# How-To Configure Virtual Network Gateway in AZURE

Tags: azure, networking, gateway

I am using AZURE and have created several webapps and one Virtual Machine.  I need all of them to be part of a virtual network so that cookies/and other packets transferred between them work properly.  I created the VM and the network at the same time.  But when I try to add networking to the webapps it shows the network but says that it does not have a gateway.

I don't know how to add a gateway to that VPN or how to make it work.  Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure point to site in your virtual network before you can connect a web application to your vnet. Basically, you need to create a gateway and then configure point to site.

Since you already have a virtual network, follow steps 4 and 5 only:

[Create a VNet with a Site-to-Site VPN connection using the Azure Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal/)

Later, configure P2S:

[Configure a Point-to-Site connection to a virtual network using PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/)

If everything goes right, you will be able to select the VNET in your app settings instead of a greyed item.

I wrote about this process a while ago and you can find my notes [here](http://www.azurekb.com.br/configuring-point-to-site-in-azure-resource-manager/).